# Hive Explode and extract a value from a String

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Folks, I'm trying to extract value of 'status' from below string(column name: people) in hive. The problem is, the column is neither a complete JSON nor stored as an Array.

I tried to make it look like a JSON by replacing '=' with ':', which didnt help.

```
[{name=abc, org=true, self=true, status=accepted, email=abc@gmail.com}, {name=cab abc, org=false, self=false, status=needsAction, email=cab@google.com}]
```

Below is the query I used:

```
SELECT 
  str.name,
  str.org, 
  str.status 
FROM table 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (TRANSLATE(people,'=',':')) exploded as str;
```

but I'm getting below error:

```
FAILED: UDFArgumentException explode() takes an array or a map as a parameter
```

Need output something like this:

```
name    | org   | status
-------- ------- ------------
abc     | true  | accepted
cab abc | false | needsAction
```

> Note: There is a table already, the datatype is string, and I
>   can't change the table schema.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Hive. It possibly can be optimized. Read comments in the code:

```
with your_table as ( --your data example, you select from your table instead
 select "[{name=abc, org=true, self=true, status=accepted, email=abc@gmail.com}, {name=cab abc, org=false, self=false, status=needsAction, email=cab@google.com}]" str
)

 select --get map values
        m['org']    as org    , 
        m['name']   as name   , 
        m['self']   as self   , 
        m['status'] as status , 
        m['email']  as email 
  from
 (--remove spaces after commas, convert to map     
  select str_to_map(regexp_replace(a.s,', +',','),',','=') m --map
    from your_table t --replace w your table
         lateral view explode(split(regexp_replace(str,'\\[|\\{|]',''),'}, *')) a as s --remove extra characters: '[' or '{' or ']', split and explode
 )s;
```

Result:

```
OK
true    abc     true    accepted        abc@gmail.com
false   cab abc false   needsAction     cab@google.com
Time taken: 1.001 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```